# python read data from file and put values into variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, text

hey stackoverflow I am needing assistance with this problem. I want to be able to read a text file that is formatted like this:

```
test: value1
test2: value2
test3(sometimes included): value3

test: value1
test2: value2

test: value1
test2: value2
test3(sometimes included): value3
```

you see test3 is sometimes included in the file and I want to be able to read it but not get it mangled up with the other values in the file.

just to make it fully clear I want to be able to read the file in python and put the values of the variables into a string in python.

here is what I have so far (this is not what I want because it gets mangled up with other values if the line doesn't have test3)

```
file = open("output.txt").readlines()

with line in file:
    if "test3" in line:
        test = find_between(...)
        test2 = find_between(...)
        test3 = find_between(...)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need re.split, here goes the code.

import re

with open("output.txt", "r") as f:

```
    for line in f:
        if "test3" not in line:
            continue

        items = re.split("[\(\)]", line)
        if len(items) > 1:
            print(items[1])
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me I don't understand why you are splitting those backslashes.

Comment: please ignore the backspashes, I meant to escape, :(

Comment: I managed to fix my issue, using re.findall :) you set me off in the right tracks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since `test` and `test2` are always there, you should not put them into the conditional block. Also note that since `test3` is optional, it's better to initialize it with `None` and later test if it is not `None` when it is to be used for something.

```
file = open("output.txt").readlines()

with line in file:
    test = find_between(...)
    test2 = find_between(...)
    test3 = None
    if "test3" in line:
        test3 = find_between(...)
    ...
    if test3 is not None:
        do_something(test3)
```

Comment: yes it works but I want to add each of them to a block so I can use for later use. e.g test1,test2,test3, I want to be able to use the value of test1 and test3 together. that is why I added the space in between each of them.